# Give a $H\le SL_{2}(\Bbb Z_p)$ such that $|H|=q$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, finite-groups

Consider $SL_{2}(\Bbb Z_p)$ if q & p be two primes, $p>q$.

Give an example of a subgroup $H\le SL_{2}(\Bbb Z_p)$ such that $|H|=q$

when i) $q|(p-1)$
     ii) $q|(p+1)$

Comment: $|SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)|=(p-1)p(p+1)$, so by Cauchy's theorem $H$ exists in both cases.

Comment: Yeah I know but I want an example of such a subgroup. Can it be given?

Comment: For example, the subgroup $H=\{ diag(a,a^{-1})\mid a\in \mathbb{F}_p^*\}$ is isomorphic to $C_{p-1}$.

Comment: & For $p+1$? . Thanks for the last example

Comment: For $q|p+1$, let $a$ be an element of multiplicative order $q$ in the finite field ${\mathbb F}_{p^2}$ of order $p^2$, and consider multiplication by $a$ as a linear transformation of ${\mathbb F}_{p^2}$ regarded as a $2$-dimensional vector space over ${\mathbb F}_{p}$.

Comment: Dickson classified *all* subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ in $1911$. This is of course more than what was asked, but a good reference.

Comment: Ok then, can you give me the soft copy of that.